# Firebase Storage - why is my file not downloading?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download a file to the device from Firebase Storage. I follow the docs and used their template for writing a file to the device, but my code below prints out `##MyApp## playMyApp downloadTask running` and then `##MyApp## playMyApp FILE DOESNT EXIST` after that. Why isn't the download working?

Note - this function is called by holding down a button.

```
Future<void> playMyApp(String MyAppURL) async {
    print('##MyApp## playMyApp 1');
    final MyAppRef = _firebaseStorage.ref().child(MyAppURL);
    print('##MyApp## playMyApp MyAppRef = ' + MyAppRef.toString());
    print('##MyApp## playMyApp MyAppRef.name = ' + MyAppRef.name);
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final filename = dir.path + receivedMyAppsDir + '/' + MyAppRef.name;
    final file = File(filename);
    print('##MyApp## playMyApp file: ' + file.path);

    try { 
      final downloadTask = MyAppRef.writeToFile(file);
      downloadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((taskSnapshot) {
        switch (taskSnapshot.state) {
          case TaskState.running:
            print('##MyApp## playMyApp downloadTask running');
            break;
          case TaskState.paused:
            print('##MyApp## playMyApp downloadTask paused');
            break;
          case TaskState.success:
            print('##MyApp## playMyApp downloadTask success');
            break;
          case TaskState.canceled:
            print('##MyApp## playMyApp downloadTask canceled');
            break;
          case TaskState.error:
            print('##MyApp## playMyApp downloadTask error');
            break;
        }
      });

    } catch (e) { 
      print('##MyApp## playMyApp ERROR: ' + e.toString());
    }

    if (await file.exists() == true) {
      print('##MyApp## playMyApp FILE EXISTS');

      await _justAudioPlayer.setFilePath(file.path);
      print('##MyApp## playMyApp setFilePath');

      await _justAudioPlayer.play();

    } else {
      print('##MyApp## playMyApp FILE DOESNT EXIST');
    }

    print('##MyApp## playMyApp 2 (finished)');
  }
```

The button's code:

```
GestureDetector(       
  onTap: () async { 

  },
  onLongPressStart: (details) async {
    print('##MyApp## MyAppWidget onLongPressStart 1');
    await playMyApp(MyAppURL);
    print('##MyApp## MyAppWidget onLongPressStart 2');
  },
  onLongPressUp: () async { 
    print('##MyApp## MyAppWidget onLongPressUp 1');
    await stopMyApp();
    print('##MyApp## MyAppWidget onLongPressUp 2');
  },
  child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {  }, child: null,),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

`downloadTask.snapshotEvents` is a stream and completes asynchronously. `TaskState.success` is the case where a file is ready for further process.

```
downloadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((taskSnapshot) {
  switch (taskSnapshot.state) {
...
    case TaskState.success:
      // TODO: File is ready for playing.
      break;
...
  }
});
```